# Is it possible to integrate a greatest integer function?

Tags: integration

Is there an indefinite integral for this function ?

$$\int [x] dx$$

I know how to integrate it if it was something like this

$$\int_b ^a [x] dx$$

Comment: The function you want would be piecewise linear, so not in closed form, but you could write down a piecewise-defined expression for it.

Comment: The downvote (with no comment) surprised me.

Comment: If a function is not continuous, can it have an antiderivative?  :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\{t\}=t-[t]$ be the fractional part of $t$. Since $\{t\}$ has period $1$ and its integral over one period is
$$
\int_x^{x+1}\{t\}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac12\tag{1}
$$
we see that
$$
\int_0^x\{t\}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac12\{x\}^2+\frac12[x]\tag{2}
$$
because $\frac12[x]$ is the integral over the complete periods and $\frac12\{x\}^2$ is the integral over the remaining part of the last period.

Thus,
$$
\int\{t\}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac12\{t\}^2+\frac12[t]+C\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\int[t]\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int\left(x-\{x\}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12x^2-\frac12\{x\}^2-\frac12[x]+C\\[3pt]
&=[x]x-\frac12[x]^2-\frac12[x]+C\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Here is a plot of $\color{#3F3D9A}{[x]}$ and $\color{#9A3D71}{(4)}$:

[image]

Note that for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, on $(k,k+1)$, the slope of $(4)$ is $k$. Since $[x]$ is not continuous at the integers, the left and right derivatives of $(4)$ do not match at the integers.

Comment: I think that's a clever but deceptive answer for a beginning calculus student. The OP  knows how to compute the corresponding definite integral and is asking about the indefinite. Is the function you wrote down differentiable at the integers? Perhaps you should add a picture and a discussion.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Since there was no context provided in the question, it was not clear this was a beginning calculus student. This is why it is important to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). In any case, I have added more explanation and an illustration.

Comment: @EthanBolker: The question asks if $\lfloor x\rfloor$ has an indefinite integral, which is slightly different than asking if it has an antiderivative. The answer I gave is an indefinite integral, although it is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @robjohn could you give me a bit help to this similar problem if possible :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080995/integrate-int-x1-dx