# Let $\int\limits_{ - 3}^t {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } dx = 51.75$. What is $t$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\int\limits_{ - 3}^t {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } dx = 51.75$.

What is $t$?

Comment: Hint: break it up into integrals over smaller intervals.

Comment: @Tp-link: You should get $t = 11.25$.

Comment: @Tp-link:  If you make no effort to solve a problem, you will not get any answers for yourself.  As far as your Readers can tell, you have not tried to work out the sort of answers that are possible, and perhaps you posted it without thinking through what the Question means.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183206/is-it-possible-to-integrate-a-greatest-integer-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : For these type of questions, always let $t= I + f$ where $I \in \mathbb
 Z$ and $0 \le f<1$.

And put $\lfloor x \rfloor = x- \lbrace x \rbrace $

Where $\lbrace . \rbrace$ denotes fractional part of $x$

Now, use periodicity of $\lbrace x \rbrace$ and separate integral into two parts i.e. $-3$ to $I$ and $I$ to $I +f$.

**Solution** : As said above -

$\int\limits_{ - 3}^t {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } dx = \int\limits_{ - 3}^{I+f} {x-\lbrace x \rbrace } dx $

$=\int\limits_{ - 3}^{I+f} {x} dx - \int\limits_{ - 3}^{I+f} {\lbrace x \rbrace } dx $

$=\int\limits_{ - 3}^{I+f} {x} dx - \int\limits_{ - 3}^{I} {\lbrace x \rbrace } dx - \int\limits_{ I}^{I+f} {\lbrace x \rbrace } dx$

$= \frac { x^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  | _{ -3 }^{ I+f } -(I+3)\int\limits_{ 0}^{1} {\lbrace x \rbrace } dx-\int\limits_{ 0}^{f} {\lbrace x \rbrace } dx $ Since $\lbrace x \rbrace $ is periodic with period $1$.

For $0$ to $1$ , $\lbrace x \rbrace=x$

$= \frac {(I+f)^2}{2}-\frac {(-3)^2}{2}- (I+3)\times \frac{1}{2}-\frac{f^2}{2} $

$(I+f)^2-9- (I+3)-f^2 = 103.5$

$I^2+2If-I=115.5  $ ............ $(\star)$

$I^2+I \ge 116$ and $I^2-I \le 115$. Since $0 \le f <1$

$\rightarrow I= 11$

Put $I=11$ in $(\star)$, you will get $f=0.25$

Hence, $t=I+f=11.25$

Answer (score 4):

You can break up the integrals into smaller parts. Start like this:
$$\int_{-3}^t {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor }~dx=\int_{-3}^{-2} -3~dx+\int_{-2}^{-1}-2~dx+\int_{-1}^{0}-1~dx+\cdots+\int_a^ta~dx \tag{1}=51.75$$
Where $a$ is some positive integer you must find. Since the integrands are constant, all you need to do is integrate repeatedly until you get close to $51.75$.

Notice that all you need to do is find the area of rectangles of width $1$:

[image]
So, for the area from $x=-3$ to $x=0$, we have:
$$\int_{-3}^0 {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor }~dx=(-3)+(-2)+(-1)=-6$$
Therefore, the area from $x=0$ to $x=t$ must be equal to:
$$\int_{0}^t {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor }~dx=51.75+6=57.75$$
Therefore:
$$\int_{0}^t {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor }~dx=\int_{0}^{1} 0~dx+\int_{1}^{2}1~dx+\int_{2}^{3}2~dx+\cdots+\int_a^t a~dx=57.75 \tag{2}$$

Can you continue? Hint: [Triangular Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: @Tp-link Is there something you have a doubt about? From my explanation, do you know what $\int_0^1 {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor }~dx$ is equal to? (Look at the graph)

Comment: What is the use of triangular numbers??

Comment: @Tp-link Notice the pattern in the values of the integrals from $x=0$:
$$\int_0^t {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor }~dx=\int_0^1 0~dx+\int_1^2 1~dx+\int_2^3 2~dx+\int_3^4 3~dx+\cdots=0+1+2+3+\cdots$$
Therefore, you can easily find the amount of integral interval separations before reaching a sum of $57.75$.

This leads to the value of $a$. Thus, you can deduce a bound for what the value of $t$. And then you can find the exact value of $t$.

Comment: :D Pictures are the best!

Answer (score 3):

Well

$\int_{n}^{n+1} \lfloor x \rfloor dx = \int_{n}^{n+1} n dx = n$, for $n \in \mathbb Z$, obviously.

So $\int_{-3}^t \lfloor x \rfloor dx = \sum_{n = -3}^{\lfloor t-1 \rfloor}\int_n^{n+1} \lfloor x \rfloor dx + \int_{\lfloor t \rfloor}^t \lfloor x \rfloor dx=$

$\sum_{n = -3}^{\lfloor t-1 \rfloor} n + [t]*(t-\lfloor t \rfloor)=$

$-6 + \frac {(t-1)t}2 + [t]*\{t\}=51.75$ where $\{t\}$ is the fractional part of $t$, i.e. $t - \lfloor t \rfloor$.

So $\frac{([t]-1)t}2= 1 + 2 + 3+ ..... + ([t]- 1) \le 57$.  That is $[t]-1 = 10$ as $\sum_{k=1}^{10} k = \frac {10*11}2 =55$.

So $[t] = 11$, (i.e. $11 \le t < 12$) and $11(t - 11) = 2.75=\frac {11}4$ so $t-11 = \frac 14$ so $t = 11\frac 14$.