# Integrate $\int [x+1] dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, indefinite-integrals

I learned about integrating GIF functions if there is definite integrals of this form: $$\int_c ^d [x+1] dx$$
But need a bit help to integrate this GIF function if there is indefinite integral of: $$\int [x+1] dx$$

p.s I searched many places including [Is it possible to integrate a greatest integer function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183206/is-it-possible-to-integrate-a-greatest-integer-function) in different form but it's hard to understand.

Need a bit help on this Calc II problem if possible.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try to graph the function first: this should help significantly.

Comment: @John Tell us what you don't understand exactly in Rob Johns answer.

Comment: @JacobAdamczyk i draw graph and understand it but don't know how to evaluate the problem cause there are no borders, it's indefinite integral

Comment: Do it for a few intervals [0,1],[1,2],[-1,0], then try a conjecture based on the pattern. As a hint your solution is an infinite sum.

Comment: @Muselive thank you i did it for some intervals, how can I represent sum of all those infinite terms

Comment: @John you don't have to. Just figure out the area under the curve. They're all rectangles so this should be nearly trivial.

Comment: @CyclotomicField all are giving different aproaches. I identified some areas of the rectangles too,there are infinite areas what should i do now.                                                       Which is considered to be the final answer of this kind of problem :(

Comment: @john the bounds are $[a,b]$. You'll need to express the areas in terms of those two numbers. Feel free to use the floor and ceiling functions to express your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using Bernoulli Polynomials**

Since the integral of $\{x\}-\tfrac12$ over a unit interval is $0$, we can write
$$
\int\left(\{x\}-\tfrac12\right)\mathrm{d}x=\tfrac12\{x\}^2-\tfrac12\{x\}+C\tag1
$$
This is the beginning of the [Bernoulli Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials). In fact, $B_1(x)=x-\frac12$ and $\frac12B_2(x)=\frac12x^2-\frac12x+\frac1{12}$.

Since $\lfloor x+1\rfloor=x+1-\{x+1\}=x+1-\{x\}$, we can use $(1)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int\lfloor x+1\rfloor\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\left(x+\tfrac12-\left(\{x\}-\tfrac12\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
&=\tfrac12x^2+\tfrac12x-\tfrac12\{x\}^2+\tfrac12\{x\}+C\tag{2b}\\[3pt]
&=\tfrac12x^2+\tfrac12x-\tfrac12\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)^2+\tfrac12\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)+C\tag{2c}\\[3pt]
&=x\lfloor x\rfloor-\tfrac12\lfloor x\rfloor^2+x-\tfrac12\lfloor x\rfloor+C\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Using a Previous Answer**

Since [an answer to the referenced question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2183226) was
$$
\int\lfloor x\rfloor\,\mathrm{d}x=\lfloor x\rfloor x-\tfrac12\lfloor x\rfloor^2-\tfrac12[x]+C\tag3
$$
we can simply substitute $x\mapsto x+1$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int\lfloor x+1\rfloor\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\color{#C00}{\lfloor x+1\rfloor(x+1)}\color{#090}{-\tfrac12\lfloor x+1\rfloor^2}\color{#00F}{-\tfrac12\lfloor x+1\rfloor}+C\tag{4a}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\lfloor x\rfloor x+x+\lfloor x\rfloor+1}\color{#090}{-\tfrac12\lfloor x\rfloor^2-\lfloor x\rfloor-\tfrac12}\color{#00F}{-\tfrac12\lfloor x\rfloor-\tfrac12}+C\tag{4b}\\[3pt]
&=\lfloor x\rfloor x-\tfrac12\lfloor x\rfloor^2+x-\tfrac12\lfloor x\rfloor+C\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, wish you all the best :)

Comment: Completely understandable elaboration, but can't get this one $x+1-\{x+1\}=x+1-\{x\}$ sorry for my late question :)

Comment: Don't worry about late questions. Some comments are posted years after the original post. Since $1\in\mathbb{Z}$, the fractional part of $x$ is the same as the fractional part of $x+1$. Think of the fractional part of $3.14159265358979$ and the fractional part of $4.14159265358979$